# JavaScript time going backwards

Tags: javascript, datetime, mongoose

In my code, I have a work shift object that uses mongoose to save a shift's start and end time into MongoDB like this

```
{
    startDateTime: new Date(2018, 1, 8, 7),
    endDateTime: new Date(2018, 1, 8, 13)
}
```

However, upon retrieving the data and printing it out via `console.log()`, the results now look like this

```
startDateTime: 2018-02-08T05:00:00.000Z,
endDateTime: 2018-02-07T16:00:00.000Z
```

I understand that when using `new Date()` it will convert to UTC time based on the local time on my development computer. However, what I don't understand is why time is going backwards if my intention is to set the date to Feb 8, 2018 7am - 1pm.

Also, how can I fix this issue such that time appears as I intend it to? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How **exactly** are you logging the date values?

Comment: You mentioned you want to set from 7am to 1pm (hours), but your 7 and 13 are in the minutes position, so your dates actually range from 1:07 to 1:13. Is that a typo?

Comment: @CRice thanks for pointing that out. I've changed the time and tried again, but I'm still having the same issue.

@Pointy These are values for work shifts. What I did was use mongoose to save those values as type "Date" into MongoDB. These values are then retrieved from a controller I've written. It executes `models.Shift.find({}).exec();` to return all shift data. With each shift as objects returned in an array, I perform `console.log()` on them and this is the output I get.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not passing a negative value in for the end time? If you used `-13` it would explain why the end date is shifted one day backwards.

Comment: What about timezones? I've had issues in the past with timezones

Comment: Again? I just answered this question tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, I'm having issues due to time zone issues. I was working on this project in North America and now I'm in Asia at the moment and I've noticed huge shifts in time. The code I'm writing now requires me to compare the start and end times of a shift with the user's specified look up date range. 

Since the shift is crossing from one day to the next, it's showing up really messed up results because local time is being converted back into UTC time. @CRice I don't have any negative value specified in my code so I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

## The Cause

The reason the date was going backwards was because I used `clearTime()` via [Date JS](http://www.datejs.com/). The purpose of `clearTime()` is to reset the time to 00:00 of the day local time. This was done via `filter()` method of the Array.protoype where I have an array of employee shifts and I'm trying to filter out the shifts by the user's requested date range versus the shifts I have in the system.

### How did it happen?

I did not suspect this would happen because Array.prorotype's `filter()` is used to specify the condition to retain an element of the array. However, the use of `clearTime()` seems to have modified the end time of the shift regardless, which triggered this time travel mystery.

### The Solution

My solution to the problem was to create a separate variable to store the end time and use JavaScript's `setUTCHours()` to forcefully set the end time of the shift to 00:00 UTC time.

### Amendments from the previous answer

The previous answer I provided for this question refers to storing time in UTC time to avoid issues with time zones. However, this leads to further complications with converting time back to local time and thus I have found an alternative solution to the problem I was encountering in efforts preserve time with time zone support. I then discovered the problem was not UTC time but due to use of [Date JS](http://www.datejs.com/).